# Similarities between static and dynamic scoping

Tags: scoping

Are there any similarities between static and dynamic scoping? I can hardly find any.

Comment: BTW, "static" scoping is also called "lexical" scoping -- i.e. it is scoped at compile-time (based on the source code), not at run-time (based on the caller).

Answer (score 0):

Static scoping or lexical scoping means that where a variable is declared can be determined by looking in the surrounding scopes. Dynamic scoping means that where a variable is declared is determined dynamically by looking up the call stack. For example:

```
var x = 2;
function foo(){ 
  return x;
}
function bar(...){
   var x = 3;
   print(foo());
}
bar();
```

With static or lexical scoping this will print 2. The x inside foo comes from the surrounding scope. With dynamic scoping this will print 3, because the value of x is determined by looking up in the call stack into the bar function invocation. At that point there is an x defined, so the value x=3 is used.

Early Lisps used dynamic scoping for all variables, but that has since been widely regarded as a mistake. Later Lisps and most other languages use lexical scoping. Some languages, like Common Lisp, do provide special dynamically scoped variables. Mainstream languages like C# and Java also have a limited form of dynamic scoping: exception handlers are usually dynamically scoped; if you raise an exception then the exception handler that is invoked is looked up dynamically on the stack, instead of determined statically by the structure of the code. For example:

```
try {
  function foo(){
    throw new Exception();
  }
} catch (Exception e){ print "A"; }

try {
  foo();
} catch (Exception e){ print "B"; }
```

This code will print "B", not "A". Note that you need to use lambda expressions to write this code in e.g. C#.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it still does not demonstrate what two have in commnon.

Comment: Well, that's like asking what an if statement and a for loop have in common. It doesn't really have a good answer ("they both have curly braces"). Since this is probably a homework question, I think that you'll get a good grade if you explained what I explained here. Or you could say something along the lines of "Both static and dynamic scoping are a way to determine where the value of a variable comes from", but that's begging the question.

Comment: The above code will work in java? foo() will have scope out of the first try block?

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a similarity between both as far as i know. there's only difference between them like @Jules explained above
In static scoping, a name refers to its closest binding, going from inner to outer scope in the program text
In  dynamic scoping, a name refers to its closest binding at runtime.